# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError with ViewPager that contains ImageViews

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, imageview, out-of-memory

I have a ViewPager in my app that contains 8 fragments, some of which contain more than 10 images, displayed in a linear layout in a column. Sometimes when swapping between the fragments the app crashes because of a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`

I have no idea how to avoid this error I think that it happens because the ViewPager and the big amount of images requires high amount of memory.

Do you have any idea on how to solve this problem?

P.S I Minimized the images quality to as low as possible.

In MainActivity onCreate method:

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    if (tabLayout != null) {
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
```

setupViewPager():

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
       
        adapter.addFragment(new S1(), getString(R.string.stage1));
        adapter.addFragment(new S2(), getString(R.string.stage2));
        adapter.addFragment(new S3(), getString(R.string.stage3));
        adapter.addFragment(new S4(), getString(R.string.stage4));
        adapter.addFragment(new S5(), getString(R.string.stage5));
        adapter.addFragment(new S6(), getString(R.string.stage6));
        adapter.addFragment(new S7(), getString(R.string.stage7));
        adapter.addFragment(new S8(), getString(R.string.stage8));
   
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

class ViewPagerAdapter:

```
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Fragemt S1:

```
public class S1 extends Fragment {

public S1() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_s1, container, false);

    ImageView image1 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_S0P1);
    ImageView image2 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_S0P2);
    ImageView image3 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_S0P3);
    ImageView image4 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_S0P4);
    ImageView image5 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_S0P5);
    ImageView image6 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_S0P6);
    ImageView image7 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_S0P7);
    ImageView image8 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_S0P8);
    ImageView image9 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_S0P9);
    ImageView image10 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_S0P10);

    image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.s0p1);
    image2.setImageResource(R.drawable.s0p2);
    image3.setImageResource(R.drawable.s0p3);
    image4.setImageResource(R.drawable.s0p4);
    image5.setImageResource(R.drawable.s0p5);
    image6.setImageResource(R.drawable.s0p6);
    image7.setImageResource(R.drawable.s0p7);
    image8.setImageResource(R.drawable.s0p8);
    image9.setImageResource(R.drawable.s0p9);
    image10.setImageResource(R.drawable.s0p10);

    return rootView;
 }
}
```

fragment_s1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/scrollView_intro"
tools:context="appinventor.ai_itiel_maimon.Rubiks_cube.s1">

 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical">

     //TextView

     <ImageView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:adjustViewBounds="true"
         android:id="@+id/imageView_S0P1"
         android:scaleType="fitCenter"
         android:contentDescription="@string/image_description" />

     <ImageView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:adjustViewBounds="true"
         android:id="@+id/imageView_S0P2"
         android:scaleType="fitCenter"
         android:contentDescription="@string/image_description" />

     //TextView

     //TextView

     <ImageView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:adjustViewBounds="true"
         android:id="@+id/imageView_S0P3"
         android:scaleType="fitCenter"
         android:contentDescription="@string/image_description" />

     <ImageView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:adjustViewBounds="true"
         android:id="@+id/imageView_S0P4"
         android:scaleType="fitCenter"
         android:contentDescription="@string/image_description" />

     //TextView

     <ImageView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:adjustViewBounds="true"
         android:id="@+id/imageView_S0P5"
         android:scaleType="fitCenter"
         android:contentDescription="@string/image_description" />

     //TextView

     <ImageView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:adjustViewBounds="true"
         android:id="@+id/imageView_S0P6"
         android:scaleType="fitCenter"
         android:contentDescription="@string/image_description" />

     <ImageView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:adjustViewBounds="true"
         android:id="@+id/imageView_S0P7"
         android:scaleType="fitCenter"
         android:contentDescription="@string/image_description" />

     //TextView

     //TextView

     <ImageView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:adjustViewBounds="true"
         android:id="@+id/imageView_S0P8"
         android:scaleType="fitCenter"
         android:contentDescription="@string/image_description" />

     <ImageView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:adjustViewBounds="true"
         android:id="@+id/imageView_S0P9"
         android:scaleType="fitCenter"
         android:contentDescription="@string/image_description" />

     //TextView

     <ImageView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:adjustViewBounds="true"
         android:id="@+id/imageView_S0P10"
         android:scaleType="fitCenter"
         android:contentDescription="@string/image_description" />

 </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Logcat:

```
07-17 20:58:31.334 30652-30652/appinventor.ai_itiel_maimon.Rubiks_cube E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: appinventor.ai_itiel_maimon.Rubiks_cube, PID: 30652
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 8876812 byte allocation with 7873968 free bytes and 7MB until OOM
at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:856)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:675)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:2228)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4211)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:4085)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:2005)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1987)
at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable(ResourcesWrapper.java:133)
at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:464)
at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompatApi21.getDrawable(ContextCompatApi21.java:26)
at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:352)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:181)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:72)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:71)
at appinventor.ai_itiel_maimon.Rubiks_cube.S7.onCreateView(S7.java:28)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2074)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachFragment(FragmentManager.java:1464)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:748)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1632)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:637)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1235)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:666)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:628)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:609)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener.onTabSelected(TabLayout.java:2168)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.dispatchTabSelected(TabLayout.java:1157)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1151)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1124)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.select(TabLayout.java:1419)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.performClick(TabLayout.java:1524)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

**EDIT:**

I used bitmaps to load the images and it gave me `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 8876812 byte allocation with 7889984 free bytes and 7MB until OOM`

This is the code I used:

Fragment S1:

```
public class Intro extends S1 {

public S1 () {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_s1, container, false);

    final int IMAGE_WIDTH  = 500;
    final int IMAGE_HEIGHT  = 500;

    ImageView image1 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_S0P1);
    ImageView image2 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_S0P2);
    ImageView image3 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_S0P3);
    ImageView image4 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_S0P4);
    ImageView image5 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_S0P5);
    ImageView image6 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_S0P6);
    ImageView image7 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_S0P7);
    ImageView image8 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_S0P8);
    ImageView image9 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_S0P9);
    ImageView image10 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_S0P10);

    image1.setImageBitmap(
            decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.s0p1, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT));
    image2.setImageBitmap(
            decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.s0p2, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT));
    image3.setImageBitmap(
            decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.s0p3, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT));
    image4.setImageBitmap(
            decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.s0p4, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT));
    image5.setImageBitmap(
            decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.s0p5, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT));
    image6.setImageBitmap(
            decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.s0p6, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT));
    image7.setImageBitmap(
            decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.s0p7, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT));
    image8.setImageBitmap(
            decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.s0p8, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT));
    image9.setImageBitmap(
            decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.s0p9, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT));
    image10.setImageBitmap(
            decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.s0p10, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT));

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                                                     int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
}
```

Comment: @Polarbear0106 How i do that?

Comment: are you using debug when running the app?

Comment: @Polarbear0106 Yes of course

Comment: Then you can see it in your IDE

Comment: What do you mean? The app is crashing and the logcat shows the java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Comment: paste the **full** logat into the question!!!

Comment: @Polarbear0106 I just did

Comment: read this: https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: @leoderprofi I did and I didn't understand how to apply this in my app.

Comment: The gist is: 
1. use bitmaps only as big as you really need  
2. reuse your bitmaps where you can.
Probably you load 10 images of 8 mb which adds up to 80 mb which is over the limit of most phones.

Comment: @leoderprofi But in my app each image is no more than 80 KB.

Comment: it is not about the size of your image on disk, but in memory. 525x525 pixels times 32 bit per pixel adds up to about 8mb of memory per image

Comment: @leoderprofi  I think you right but I have no idea where to put this code. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: @leoderprofi See my updated question

Comment: it crashes in S7 not in S1, so post the code for that

Comment: @leoderprofi No. It crashes in different fragments every time, no just S7, it changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using the Fresco library to load the images. It's very helpful! http://frescolib.org

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities, depending on what you want to achieve:

1.

You can reduce

```
final int IMAGE_WIDTH  = 500;
final int IMAGE_HEIGHT  = 500;
```

to

```
final int IMAGE_WIDTH  = 250;
final int IMAGE_HEIGHT  = 250;
```

that way you will reduce the memory footprint of the images by a factor of 4.

2.

Add

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

to your manifest (see [application tag documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html)). This will give you more heap space, but it is not guaranteed to work on all devices.

3.

use `RGB_565` in your `BitmapFactory.Options`

```
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
```

[Bitmap.Config](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html)
to reduce your bitmaps to half the size, when you don't need alpha. This will impact the image quality though.

Answer (score 0):

Please, consider to you [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html) instead of FragmentPagerAdapter and in each fragment use [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) instead of layout with many images. This will reduce memory usage and thus fix your OOM issue.

Comment: The FragmentStatePagerAdapte doesn't avoid the eror.

Comment: I can't use RecyclerView because there are more different textViews inside each fragment.

Comment: Different textView? What differs them? Content? Then you can create array of objects with settings for each item of recycler view.

Comment: Also please check sizes of all images that you use. If you try to place, for example, 12 pictures with each sizes of 10MB in screen, then you will have a problem.

Comment: Each image is no more than 80 KB.

Comment: Could you please provide a stacktrace for OOM, when you use FragmentStatePagerAdapter?

Comment: It's give me the exact same stacktrace

Comment: Then try to remain only one fragment in you ViewPager. If OOM will still persist, then you need to look closer to drawables that you use in that fragment, and then please provide XML layout of that fragment.

Comment: @leoderprofi is right. If you have 10 images in S1 fragment and they all do not fit screen, so most of them out of screen, then consider to user recycler view, as I sad earlier.

Comment: How can I remain only one fragment in my ViewPager?

Comment: And how can I use recycler view in my case?

Comment: Delete all other fragment. You need to remain only one just for test. I don't know, how you can use RecyclerView, because I don't see your code. But probably, if you have same layouts for all items, that you can do it simply, just check few tutorials.

Comment: You xml layout look like it need to be replaced with RecyclerView. Could you please create a test layout with RecyclerView instead of all of that. Items of this recycler view will be imageViews (just ignore textViews for know, we just need to check, that we thinking in the right direction). Just Recycler view, simple adapter with holder (there are a lot of tutorials about that) and  fill each item with appropriate image. Then tell me please about your results.